# Can't scan to network folder on Ricoh Aficio MP C305

Tags: networking, multi-function-printer

This has been frustrating me for many months now.

I can't use the scanning functionality on a Ricoh Aficio MP C305 because it can't connect to anything on the network.

It sees the WORKGROUPS but just won't connect to anything. Even though it has correct usernames/passwords (if required).

Anything else on the network can connect to the same paths fine so I know it is not a sharing/permissions issue on the network location. It seems something specific to the printer/scanner/copier device and I've got no idea how to fix it.

I've got full admin access to the web interface (Web Image Monitor).

This did use to work by the way. I'm not sure when it actually stopped working.

I tried looking for a firmware update but [couldn't even see any firmware of Ricoh's website](http://support.ricoh.com/bb/html/dr_ut_e/re1/model/mpc305/mpc305.htm).

If for example, we use my Windows 10 PC as an example. The Ricoh Aficio can see it on the network, and the shared folders within it. It just doesn't scan to the folder. I'm not even sure how to bring up error logs or anything. If someone can guide me then I will provide more information here.

Comment: "This did use to work by the way."  <-- Ask Ricoh Support if the unit requires SMBv1 support to connect.  That may be the case and SMBv1 is pretty much gone.

Comment: Thanks @John - On the Windows 10 PC containing the shared folder I want to scan to, this has SMB 1.0/CIFS Client and SMB Direct enabled in the Windows Features - if that helps?

Comment: Enabling SMBv1 on Windows 10 is a serious security issue.  Did you ask Ricoh Support?

Comment: I did speak to them but they can't offer any support because the contract is under a third party company who we binned ages ago so I've got to wait for someone to call me back in the New Year just to look into setting up a new support contract.